# Player of the year awards

Tags: basketball, collegiate, awards

Has any player won both the Naismith player of the year and defensive player of the year in the same season before 2021-22?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, but it's not a very interesting one: the Naismith Defensive Player of the Year awards have only been given out since 2018.  See [the awards page](https://naismithtrophy.com/winners/) for the list of players who won; Aliyah Boston from South Carolina is the first men's or women's player to win both awards.